# Proving domination of a function with mixed convexity property by an affine function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, convex-analysis

Let  $F:[0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ be a $C^2$ function satisfying $F(1)=0, F(0)=1$, which is strictly strictly decreasing on $[0,1]$. Furthermore, suppose that for some $a \in(0,1)$,  $F'' < 0$ on $[0,a)$ and $F'' > 0$ on $(a,1]$.

Let $s \in (a,1]$ be the unique point satisfying $\frac{F(s)-F(0)}{s-0}=F'(s)$, and let $l:[0,s] \to [1,F(s)]$ be the affine function (line) connecting the points $(0,1),(s,F(s))$.

> How to prove that $l(x) \le F(x)$ for every $x \in [0,s]$?

*I am actually interested in proving this under the weaker assumption that $F \in C^1$ and is $C^2$ on $[0,a)$,$(a,1]$ but not twice differentiable at $a$. (More accurately, $F|_{[0,a]},F|_{[a,1]}$ are $C^2$, but their second derivatives do not agree at $a$).

---

The motivation comes from trying to compute the convex envelope of [this function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808452/how-to-calculate-explicitly-this-convex-envelope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue as follows:

- $l$ is a tangent at the graph of $F$, which implies that $F(x) \ge l(x)$ for $a \le x \le 1$ where $F$ is convex.
- Then $F(0) = l(0)$ and $F(a) \ge l(a)$ implies $F(x) \ge l(x)$ for $0 \le x \le a$ where $F$ is concave.

Comment: Thanks. First, I think that $\frac{F(a)-F(0)}{a-0} <F'(a)$ cannot happen, thus there always exists such an $s$. The reason is the concavity of $F$ on $[0,a)$- $F'$ is decreasing there. Also, could you please elaborate on how do you see that $F(a) \ge l(a)$? Thanks.

Comment: @AsafShachar: You are right about the existence, I'll remove that part. – $F$ is convex on $[a, 1]$ therefore it lies above the tangent line $l$ on that interval. In particular, $F(a) \le l(a)$.